# Tkinter .get method query

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So I'm trying to make a GUI that allows a user to choose an mp3 file to play. The chosen file is displayed in a listbox and I'm using the Pygame module for playing the file. For playing a file a path is needed and I wanted to know if there's a way by which I can get the path of an ACTIVE object in the listbox.

Comment: One might well be able to make a listbox function as a file dialog with some work...but thinking maybe you want to checkout using a file dialog widget instead: https://pythonbasics.org/tkinter-filedialog/

Comment: The question can be answered by reading the documentation for the listbox. Please attempt to solve this yourself, and then post a [mcve] if you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following command : `listbox.get(listbox.curselection())`